# symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'

Tags: python, dlib, libpng

I'm working on a project on my MacBook with M1 chip. I want to restore old pictures. I have problems with glib.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/florian/Documents/workspace_python/Bringing-Old-Photos-Back-to-Life/Face_Detection/detect_all_dlib.py", line 24, in <module>
    import dlib
  File "/usr/local/lib/miniforge3/envs/picrestore/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dlib/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    from _dlib_pybind11 import *
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/miniforge3/envs/picrestore/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_dlib_pybind11.cpython-39-darwin.so, 0x0002): symbol not found in flat namespace '_png_do_expand_palette_rgb8_neon'
```

What I tried:

- reinstall dlib with pip (not brew)
- checked installation of tensorflow-macos and tensorflow-metal

Had anyone had a similar problem?

Comment: Exactly same here - no solution yet